# How to deal with underflow in java?

Tags: java, underflow

Here's the issue

```
double a = 1.0665901062490447E-18;
double b = 1.0;
double c = a+b; // this is 1.0
```

I need that summed value. What do I do about it?

Comment: `1.0665901062490447E-18` is a **very** small value.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yup, I know. is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Don't use doubles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58513780/how-to-deal-with-underflow-in-java/58513821#comment103354738_58513780), `1.0665901062490447E-18` is a **very** small value. If you need that much precision, you should be using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Something like,

```
double a = 1.0665901062490447E-18, b = 1.0;
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(a).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(b)).toPlainString());
```

Which outputs

```
1.0000000000000000010665901062490447
```

Note that there is a predefined constant [`BigDecimal.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ONE) - so the above could also be written

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(a).add(BigDecimal.ONE).toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to what primitive types can do in almost any language. In this case, the `double` type I believe is bound by [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). In order to handle these class of problems [Arbitrary Precision Libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) have been created for many languages.

The classic ["What Every Computer Scientist
Should Know About Floating Point
Arithmetic"](https://cr.yp.to/2005-590/goldberg.pdf) is required reading for all uses of floating point data types.